# How to access a specific element in JSON in Google Apps Script?

Tags: javascript, json, google-apps-script

I need to access the nav for a specific date from the below JSON. eg : data[date="20-04-2022"].nav
How do I do it in Google Apps Script?
The standard JSON notation is not working.

```
{
   "meta":{
      "fund_house":"Mutual Fund",
      "scheme_type":"Open Ended Schemes",
   },
   "data":[
      {
         "date":"22-04-2022",
         "nav":"21.64000"
      },
      {
         "date":"21-04-2022",
         "nav":"21.69000"
      },
      {
         "date":"20-04-2022",
         "nav":"21.53000"
      }
   ],
   "status":"SUCCESS"
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "Standard notation is not working"? Please add a [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your situation, I thought that it is required to retrieve the element including `"date": "20-04-2022"` from the array of `data`. So, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

```js
const obj = {
  "meta": {
    "fund_house": "Mutual Fund",
    "scheme_type": "Open Ended Schemes",
  },
  "data": [
    {
      "date": "22-04-2022",
      "nav": "21.64000"
    },
    {
      "date": "21-04-2022",
      "nav": "21.69000"
    },
    {
      "date": "20-04-2022",
      "nav": "21.53000"
    }
  ],
  "status": "SUCCESS"
};
const search = "20-04-2022";
const res = obj.data.find(({ date }) => date == search);
const value = res && res.nav;
console.log(value) // 21.53000
```

- For example, if the search value is always found, you can use the following script.

  ```
    const res2 = obj.data.find(({ date }) => date == search).nav;
  ```

#### Reference:

- [find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

### Added 1:

From your following reply,

> This looks like standard java script. Does not work in google apps script(script.google.com/home). Getting syntax error for this line : const res = obj.data.find(({ date }) => date == search);

I'm worried that you are not enabling V8 runtime. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/v8-runtime#enabling_the_v8_runtime) If you cannot use V8 runtime, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

```js
var obj = {
  "meta": {
    "fund_house": "Mutual Fund",
    "scheme_type": "Open Ended Schemes",
  },
  "data": [
    {
      "date": "22-04-2022",
      "nav": "21.64000"
    },
    {
      "date": "21-04-2022",
      "nav": "21.69000"
    },
    {
      "date": "20-04-2022",
      "nav": "21.53000"
    }
  ],
  "status": "SUCCESS"
};
var search = "20-04-2022";
var res = obj.data.filter(function (e) { return e.date == search })[0];
var value = res && res.nav;
console.log(value) // 21.53000
```

### Added 2:

From your following reply,

> This looks like standard java script. Does not work in google apps script(script.google.com/home). Getting syntax error for this line : const res = obj.data.find(({ date }) => date == search);

> I am trying to write a google apps script to fetch data from a url. But google seems to have its own way of handling the JSON data which I am unable to figure out. developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/…

I understood that your actual goal was to retrieve the value using Web Apps. If my understanding of your actual goal, how about the following sample script?

#### 1. Sample script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor and save the script.

```js
function doGet(e) {
  var search = e.parameter.search;
  var obj = {
    "meta": {
      "fund_house": "Mutual Fund",
      "scheme_type": "Open Ended Schemes",
    },
    "data": [
      {
        "date": "22-04-2022",
        "nav": "21.64000"
      },
      {
        "date": "21-04-2022",
        "nav": "21.69000"
      },
      {
        "date": "20-04-2022",
        "nav": "21.53000"
      }
    ],
    "status": "SUCCESS"
  };
  var res = obj.data.filter(function (e) { return e.date == search })[0];
  var value = res && res.nav;
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(value);
}
```

- I think that this sample script can be used with and without V8 runtime.

#### 2. Deploy Web Apps.

In this case, please check [the official document](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web#deploy_a_script_as_a_web_app). Please set it as follows.

- `Execute as: Me`
- `Anyone with Google account: Anyone`

**In this case, it supposes that you are using new IDE. Please be careful this.**

#### 3. Testing.

Please access to the URL like `https://script.google.com/macros/s/{deploymentId}/exec?search=20-04-2022` using your browser. By this, the result value is returned.
`

Comment: This looks like standard java script. Does not work in google apps script(https://script.google.com/home). Getting syntax error for this line : const res = obj.data.find(({ date }) => date == search);

Comment: @Nash From `Getting syntax error for this line : const res = obj.data.find(({ date }) => date == search);`, I have a question. In your situation, you are enabling V8 runtime? I'm worried about this. If you are not enabling V8 runtime, please enable it and test it again. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/v8-runtime#enabling_the_v8_runtime)

Comment: @Nash If you cannot use V8 runtime, how about the additional sample script? But, if I misunderstood your actual goal, I apologize.

Comment: I am trying to write a google apps script to fetch data from a url.  But google seems to have its own way of handling the JSON data which I am unable to figure out. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/external#work_with_json

Comment: Hi @Nash the code from this answer is perfectly appropriate for Apps Script. If it's not working for you (1) make sure you've enabled V8, (2) explain what error you are getting, (3) provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @Nash Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. From `I am trying to write a google apps script to fetch data from a url. But google seems to have its own way of handling the JSON data which I am unable to figure out. developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/…`, I couldn't notice that you wanted to use Web Apps. I deeply apologize for my poor English skill. For your actual goal, I added one more sample script. Could you please confirm it? If I cannot still notice your actual goal, I apologize again.

Comment: @Iamblichus Thank you for your always support. From OP's reply, I guessed that OP wanted to retrieve the result value using Web Apps. So I added the sample script. But, unfortunately, I'm not sure whether my understanding is correct.

Comment: Thank You. It is working after enabling V8 runtime.

Comment: @Nash Thank you for replying and testing it again. I'm glad your issue was resolved.